# connection to port 22 refused before asking for username/pword

Tags: ssh, connection

I've added an empty ssh file to the /boot directory. When I run `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local`, I get this error: `ssh: connect to host raspberrypi.local port 22: Connection refused` without being asked for my password or username. If I run `ssh localhost` I get the expected response. I've also enabled Remote Login on my laptop, and have turned my computer firewall off.

Please help!!

Comment: are you trying to log in from the laptop to the pi? because remote login on the laptop or firewall won't effect ability to SSH into the pi ... you say you added ssh file to "/boot" ... do you mean you've added it to the first partition on the SD card before plugging it into the pi itself? Oh, and, are you using NOOBS by any chance?

Comment: Yes I'm trying to login from the laptop to the pi. Yes to adding the file to the SD card before plugging it into the pi, as well. I don't think I'm using NOOBS (not sure what that is)

Comment: so, after you've booted the pi, does the file `ssh` still exist in the first partition? can you log in to the pi using keyboard/mouse/tv to check it's booting OK?

Comment: oh, NOOBS is the abomination Raspberry Pi foundation thought was good for "noobs" - as it turns out, it's the worst piece of crap you can use on a Raspberry pi

Comment: So after I connect the SD card to my pi, I should put it back into my computer and check if the ssh file is there?

Comment: when you said *If I run `ssh localhost`* - where did you run that? on the pi? also, how did you flash the SD card in the first place? What software did you use? Which image did you flash?